# .Net Synclock Read-Methods Only When Updating

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

How can I allow a method to be called simultaneously from multiple threads without locking, but where it WILL lock while a different method is called?

Example:

```
Private DataLock As New Object()

Private Function GetInfo() As String
    SyncLock DataLock 
        'Read existing data and return a String
    End SyncLock
End Function

Private Sub UpdateData()
    SyncLock DataLock 
        'Update/Change existing Data
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

How do I modify the above code so that:

- `UpdateData()` always triggers the lock when called, locking both itself and `GetInfo`
- `GetInfo()` does not lock itself (so it can run simultaneously on multiple threads), but it DOES lock `UpdateData` until it is finished

Comment: For something like that, you could use Semaphores.  I'm not familiar enough with them to tell you how, but it gives you something to Google.

Comment: You might look at the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class. It is specifically intended to allow multiple readers or a single writer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, I believe `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is a good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the direct analogue to the code you posted using the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class:

```
Private dataLock As New ReaderWriterLockSlim()

Private Function GetInfo() As String
    dataLock.EnterReadLock()

    Try
        'Read existing data and return a String
    Finally
        dataLock.ExitReadLock()
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub UpdateData()
    dataLock.EnterWriteLock()

    Try
        'Update/Change existing Data
    Finally
        dataLock.ExitWriteLock()
    End Try
End Sub
```

You might want to consider the `Try` methods though, which allow you to specify a maximum time to wait for the lock.

Comment: The `Try...Finally` appears to be necessary, since `dataLock.ExitReadLock` would otherwise not happen if it comes after the return statement

Comment: I'm not sure whether your comment was in reference to the last statement in my answer but when I referred to `Try` methods I was not referring to the `Try...Finally` statements but rather the use of `TryEnterReadLock` and `TryEnterWriteLock`.